# composer install -n --ignore-platform-reqs not ignoring PHP extension

Tags: drupal, composer-php, circleci

we have circle build that runs `composer install -n --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev` but this is not ignoring the platform requirements anymore.

This is what i see in the circle log. The `--ignore-platform-reqs` is clearly not working. Any ideas why please?

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for drupal/core 8.6.13 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.13].
    - drupal/core 8.6.13 requires ext-pdo * -> the requested PHP extension pdo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v2.1.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v2.1.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v2.1.0 -> satisfiable by typo3/phar-stream-wrapper[v2.1.0].
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using `--ignore-platform-reqs` or `provide` hack it is better to mimic your environment using [`platform`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) setting - it gives you more control about platform requirements and it is more intuitive than `provide` (your package does not really provide `ext-fileinfo`):

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.2.14",
        "ext-fileinfo": "1.0.5",
        "ext-pdo": "7.2.14",
        "ext-session": "7.2.14",
        "ext-iconv": "7.2.14",
        "ext-zip": "1.15.4"
    }
},
```

Actual versions of extensions you may find by calling this command on production environment (although you could probably put anything for extensions version - it is quite uncommon to use anything except `*` as a constraint for PHP extensions):

```
composer show -p
```

Comment: I tried adding that in the `platform` but I got this error                            
  [UnexpectedValueException]  
  Invalid version string "*"

Comment: Thanks @rob . `composer show -p` helped. was able to get the right version for that. I do have one more suggestion that I need for `composer.json` file. I have a    ` "minimum-stability": "dev"`,  and ` "prefer-stable": true,` in my composer.json file but whenever I am trying to install a module for drupal using this command `composer require 'drupal/file_mdm:^1.1'` its downloading the dev version and not the stable version causing issues with my build. The dev version has `.git` folder in it and its creating issues with my repo. how do i force composer to download the stable version over dev?

Comment: I'm not familiar with drupal and its repositories, but you may try `--prefer-dist` switch. Downloading package from source does not directly depends on its stability - you may use stable release and still have `.git` directory inside.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using `--prefer-dist` but that didn't resolve it. will do more research. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer my own question just in case somebody stumbles here. Adding a provide with the list of extension in my `composer.json` file resolved the issue for me. This `--ignore-platform-reqs` had no effect.

```
 "provide": {
        "ext-fileinfo": "*",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "ext-session": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*"
    }
```

Comment: i would not recommend this, this way you will not see the errors on a live environment which does not have those. better add it to the global config in your home directory as stated in first solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I took it out from `provide` and added it in my `platform` settings.