# How to handle missing dependencies with composer & docker?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I have an application that I want to install for local development on my laptop with Docker. The application requires libraries from composer.

I would like to avoid installing PHP on my laptop and all necessary extensions just to be able to run composer.

I also don't want to run composer during the build inside of my application container, because I need the vendor folder on my local computer using mount binding.

It looked like the perfect solution to me to install composer though a docker container as explained [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer):

```sh
docker run --rm --interactive --tty \
  --volume $PWD:/app \
  composer install
```

However, when doing so, how do you resolve any PHP dependency conflicts?

For example

```sh
docker run --rm --interactive --tty \
       --volume $PWD:/app \
       composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

will fail with

```
Using version ^1.14 for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.14 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.14.0, 1.14.1].
```

How can I solve this kind of problems?

Comment: you need to create your custom docker image where you install the dependencies in the in the Dockerfile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [composer install -n --ignore-platform-reqs not ignoring PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426273/composer-install-n-ignore-platform-reqs-not-ignoring-php-extension)

Comment: ```apt-get install php-gd ```

Comment: ```composer require foo/bar --ignore-platform-reqs ```   you can install without requirements

Answer (score 2):

When the environment where you are running `install`, `update` or `require` commands is different from the environment where you are going to execute the code, and if you are absolutely certain that these dependencies are going to be met when the code is actually run, you do not need to check them during installation.

Just use `--ignore-platform-reqs` ([docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i)).

What I usually put in my Dockerfiles when creating images for this kind of project is something like this, the the very minimum:

```sh
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist
```

The whole thing goes like this if the artefact is being prepared for production:

```sh
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist --no-scripts \
 --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction --no-dev --no-autoloader
```

A couple additional steps to dump-autoload and execute post-install scripts are going to be needed in this case.

You do not elaborate how are you planning on running the result of this installation afterwards, so I'm not sure that part will be relevant for you.

Note: this is not particularly "docker" dependant. This strategy would apply any time you are creating an installation on a different machine than were you plan on *running* the installation.